# Save values from DataGridview, show them everytime after opening

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, save

I have a question about saving values of Datatable or DataGridView. I made a windows form and binded datatable to datagridview. Now i want the values from this datagridview be there everytime i open the windows form. Because sometimes the user add some rows to DGV and when i open it again, the rows are not there any more. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Are these values being written back to the Database from each user..? if so then you need to run a query to load and display the data in the DataGridView.. how are you displaying the data currently.. what code do you have Le Viet Hung

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that in this way.
When user adds a row to DataGridView, you can add that row to DGV just for showing it to user. But when the program is closing you can add that rows to the source of DGV, from where you read all data.